# Using extractvalue to get XML attribute

Tags: mysql

Using MySQl, I am trying to use `extractvalue` to find the value of an XML node's attribute. What should the `extractvalue` command look like?

Example -

```
SET @xml = '<a>
              <b thing="09876"></b>
            </a>'

SELECT extractvalue(@xml,'???')
```

What would the command look like to display the value of 'thing'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `attribute::<attributename>` to the XPath:

```
SELECT extractvalue(@xml,'/a/b/attribute::thing')
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/DLZLO67761)